# Адаптивное модальное окно

Tags: javascript, css

Есть кнопка:

```
<a href="#" class="to_contact">Нажать</a>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии ее, по середине экрана появлялось адаптивное модальное окно с 3 полями для ввода и 2 кнопками закрыть и продолжить.

Как реализовать это без bootstrap?

Comment: хотим быть в курсе, когда что-то наконец-то получится!

Answer (score 2):

Вот, пожалуйста:

```css
.modalDialog {
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  display: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  display: block;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Открыть модальное окно</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Закрыть" class="close">x</a>
    <h2>Модальное окно</h2>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <a href="#">Продолжить</a><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: оно открывается не совсем по середине, а чуть выше, можешь изменить пожалуйста.

Comment: это хорошо заметно когда выводишь на фулл экран

Comment: .modalDialog>div {  margin: 10% auto;} п.с. 10% - регулируй, как тебе нужно.

Comment: @Sergio, если ответ помог, выбери ответ и поставь +1